# Exact setup behavior description, when prerequisite needs a reboot

Tags: installshield

Using InstallShield 2018, I added Visual C++ 2015-2022 Runtime prerequisite to InstallShield setup project. When VC++ Runtime is installed first time on some computer, it may request reboot. The behavior of the setup is defined in InstallShield Prerequisite editor:

[image: Setup behavior]

I selected the last option: Reboot the machine and resume on reboot. Resulting behavior: VC++ Runtime is installed, and computer goes to reboot, even without user prompt. After reboot, setup resumes.

I want to have the following behavior: If prerequisite needs a reboot, setup continues. In the end, when the product is installed, setup should ask user to reboot, user may accept or reject this.

What option in the list should I select, to get desired behavior? Their description is not clear enough.

Comment: By the way, it is quite difficult to test all behaviors. Once VC++ Runtime is installed, it will never request reboot again, even if I uninstall it. So, I need clean computer for every test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third option should get the desired behavior.

> Note it, fail to resume if the machine is rebooted, and reboot after the installation.

For artificial reboot, you might play with 'PendingFileRenameOperations' value in the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager